# Divergent sequence proof verification

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried to prove that series as follows is divergent:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\left (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}+ ... + \frac{\left (-1 \right )^n}{2n}\right )$$
We can see that sequence is alike to harmonic, therefore should be divergent by Leibnitz's criterion. Is it correct to factor out $\frac{1}{n}$ to prove it?:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n} \left (1 - \frac{n}{n+1}+ ... + \frac{\left (-1 \right )^n n}{2n}\right )$$

Comment: My first try would be to manually compute and study $$\sum^{10}_{n=1}\left (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}+ ... + \frac{\left (-1 \right )^n}{2n}\right ).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{n+1}+\dots +\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}.$$

Notice that when $n$ is even, we would have had $n+1$ (odd) terms from $n$ to $2n$. Grouping them as follows, we are led to:

$$ \left(\frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{n+1}\right) +\dots+\left(\frac{1}{2n-2}-\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)+\frac{1}{2n} \geq \frac{1}{2n},$$
as each bracketed term is positive and the last term is also positive.

When $n$ is odd, then the number of terms from $n$ to $2n$, which is $n+1$, is even. Grouping them as follows, we can conclude that:
$$\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)+\dots +\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right) \geq 0,$$
as each bracketed term is positive.

Thus, for all $n\geq 1$:

$$a_{2n} \geq \frac{1}{4n}$$

and

$$a_{2n-1} \geq 0.$$

Hence

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4n},$$
which is divergent.

Comment: I didn't understand what was the problem here for a down vote !

Comment: I've no idea who downvoted. Anyway, when $\;k=2n\;$ is even there are exactly the same number of even and odd indexed elements in $\;a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_{2n}\;$ . When $\;k=2n+1\;$ is odd there are $\;n+1\;$ odd-indexed elements and $\;n\;$ even ones.

Comment: I had done a mistake. Rectified the same. Between, did you find any mistake in the above answer?